# See specific flyway SQL queries

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I'm seeing flyway seemingly skip migration "V.*" scripts and fail on a later script. Script V1 creates a table, then script V2 alters it. Except that no table gets created, the database is a fresh DB2 instance then it legitimately complains when an alter is attempted.

I have a related question still open, but it would be helpful to get Spring-Boot/Flyway to log the specific SQL that was tried. Not looking for a log of the SQL migration, but the *exact* SQL in the migration that was attempted.

I tried adding -Dlogging.level.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript=DEBUG but didn't see any change.